# How do I configure TS to find the types for @testing-library/jest-dom

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, tsconfig

This is my tsconfig file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src",
      "../.redwood/types/mirror/web/src",
      "../api/src",
      "../.redwood/types/mirror/api/src"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*",
        "../.redwood/types/mirror/web/src/*",
        "../api/src/*",
        "../.redwood/types/mirror/api/src/*"
      ],
      "$api/*": [ "../api/*" ],
      "types/*": ["./types/*", "../types/*"],
      "@redwoodjs/testing": ["../node_modules/@redwoodjs/testing/web"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "../.redwood/types/includes/all-*",
    "../.redwood/types/includes/web-*",
    "../types",
    "./types"
  ]
}
```

When I run `tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck` I get this error

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@testing-library/jest-dom'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library '@testing-library/jest-dom' specified in compilerOptions

  tsconfig.json:29:23
    29     "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is entry point of type library specified here.


Found 1 error.
```

This is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 1 version"
    ],
    "production": [
      "defaults"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@redwoodjs/auth-dbauth-web": "7.0.0-canary.711",
    "@redwoodjs/forms": "7.0.0-canary.711",
    "@redwoodjs/router": "7.0.0-canary.711",
    "@redwoodjs/web": "7.0.0-canary.711",
    "humanize-string": "2.1.0",
    "react": "0.0.0-experimental-e5205658f-20230913",
    "react-dom": "0.0.0-experimental-e5205658f-20230913"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@redwoodjs/vite": "7.0.0-canary.711",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.15",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "0.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to make TS find the types for `@testing-library/jest-dom`?

More details:

This worked with @testing-library/jest-dom v5, but broke when we upgraded to v6

If I remove it from `types` in tsconfig I get type errors about missing properties (see comments). I can work around that by including
`import '@testing-library/jest-dom'` in one of my test files. But I didn't have to do that before, and I want to understand why I have to now.

Comment: Can you give a [mre]? Testing Library comes with type definitions built in, and an `exports` map telling other tools where to find them - a very simple setup does seem to.

Comment: Remove that line from your tsconfig, that is for [*limiting* the globally available type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types). Unless you have a very good reason, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @JaredSmith If I remove it TS complains about `Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<any>'.` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to change my tsconfig.json from this:

```
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
```

to this:

```
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@types", "../node_modules/@testing-library"],
    "types": ["jest", "jest-dom"],
```

The types for `@testing-library/jest-dom` used to be provided by https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/testing-library__jest-dom but now they're shipped with the main package itself. Because of this it's no longer enough to just look in `node_modules/@types`. I now needed to tell TS to also look for types in `../node_modules/@testing-library`, so I added that to `typeRoots`. And inside that path, it should look for the types "jest-dom", as specified in `types`.